# Distance between line and point with shared ID

Tags: qgis, vector, distance, virtual-layer

I have a point layer and a line layer with matching ID fields.

I want to calculate the shortest distance between points and lines where the ID matches.

They are not always the closest features to each other.

Example of what I mean:

[image]

it can either be a line output or an attribute that shows distance

On a small test dataset I can achieve this using the PostGIS query below.

```
SELECT ST_ShortestLine(l.geometry, p.geometry),
            p.id AS pid,
            l.id AS lid,
            ROUND(ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(l.geometry, p.geometry)), 4) AS distance 
FROM points AS p, lines AS l 
WHERE p.id = l.id 
GROUP BY p.id 
ORDER BY MIN(distance)
```

However, I am working on a large dataset with 400,000 points and 200,000 lines and this method seems to be too inefficient, causing QGIS to go into not responding for hours.

Comment: I would recommend to write the results from the postgis query into a new table since on-the-fly solutions with QGIS (expressions, geometry-generator...) will be inefficient and slow too

Comment: @eurojam Would you mind explaining how to do that?

Comment: SELECT ST_ShortestLine(l.geom, p.geom),
            p.id AS pid,
            l.id AS lid,
            ST_Length(ST_ShortestLine(l.geom, p.geom)) AS distance 
INTO connections
FROM points AS p, lines AS l 
WHERE p.id = l.id

Comment: `SELECT <query> INTO <table>` is an outdated non-standard SQL syntax - better use `CREATE TABLE <table> AS <query>`. Is that data actually stored in PostgreSQL? If not, the query is executed on a *SpatiaLite* backend.

Comment: @geozelot The data is not stored on PostgreSQL. What do you mean by the query is executed on a SpatiaLite backend?

Comment: There is no "*PostGIS query*" outside of a PostgreSQL/PostGIS RDBS. Queries on arbitrary data sources in the *Virtual Layer* SQL console are executed inline on a *SpatiaLite (SQLite core)* backend. So you are running a non-optimized query on an unindexed data collection.